# Is possible center <g> in <svg>?

Tags: svg

I searched on the web and I do not found a solution for my problem, is possible to do that, center my element depending of size of my parent content.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#333">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2">
      <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
      <path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18">
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          type="rotate"
          from="0 18 18"
          to="360 18 18"
          dur="1s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: In your example what exactly do you need to center ?

Comment: the loader itself

Comment: Center horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: @j08691 both friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the loader in a `symbol`. Also I would give the loader and the svg element a `viewBox` attribute.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="100%"  viewBox="-250 -50 500 100"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#333">
  <symbol id="the_symbol"  viewBox="-2 -2 40 40">
    <g stroke-width="2">
      <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
      
      <path d="M36 18A18,18 0 0 0 0,18">
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          type="rotate"
          from="0 18 18"
          to="360 18 18"
          dur="1s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#the_symbol" x="-20" y="-20" width="36" height="36" fill="none"  />
  
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

The OP is commenting that they want the root svg to take various sizes, while the loader has to be always the same size.

```js
//the size and position of the symbol
let o = {x:36,y:18}

function init(){
  
  let p = getsize(o);
  //reset the size and position of the use element
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"width",p.x)
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"height",p.x)
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x",250-p.y)
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y",50-p.y)
}


// a function to calculate the size and position of the use element
function getsize(o){
var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
p.x= o.x;
p.y= o.y;
p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
return p
}

setTimeout(function() {
  init();
  addEventListener('resize', init, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
symbol{overflow:visible}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"   viewBox="0 0 500 100"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#333">
  <symbol id="the_symbol"  viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <g stroke-width="2">
      <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
      
      <path d="M36 18A18,18 0 0 0 0,18">
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          type="rotate"
          from="0 18 18"
          to="360 18 18"
          dur="1s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#the_symbol" fill="none"  />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: that is good, but i need the same loader size of the question, how can put the equal size? thanks

Comment: I've changed the symbol size to `width="36" height="36"`

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, and I need que the size of the loader always be the same in all screens, but it is not happen

Comment: Why do you need the SVG to have `width= "100%"`

Comment: I need that component in various parts of my page and in differents sizes

Comment: you need the root svg to take various sizes, while the loader has to be allways the same size?

Comment: Exactly, I need that

Comment: @enxaneta How difficult it is sometimes to earn points for questions that at first glance seemed simple